# По нажатию на ImageView выводить его содержимое на весь экран

Tags: android

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть ImageView в одном активити. Я привязал у нему OnClickListener.
Мне нужно обратиться к нему как к View, и получить его ресурс (его картинку).

Затем передать либо путь к этой картинке, либо еще как-то в другое активити, в котором есть второй ImageView, которое уже размечено на весь экран и ждет, пока ему передадут путь первой картинки (чтобы вывести ее на полный экран).

Я себе это так представляю.

Помогите, пожалуйста, с реализацией.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Как картинки на первом активити организованы? Я думаю лучше диалог показать с картинкой.

Comment: На первом активити есть imageView, не на весь экран, и в нем есть картинка. Я хочу, чтобы по нажатию на этот ImageView эта картинка разворачивалась во весь экран.